# Delete/add/replace pages in PDF while preserving bookmarks

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, pdf, kubuntu, pdftk

Is there an easy CLI method to do that? 
If I use `pdftk`, I get a new pdf without the bookmarks of the original one. The bookmarks were created on another system with Adobe Acrobat Pro, and an example is available [here](http://www.novapdf.com/uploads/novapdf_en/media_items/pdf-example-bookmarks.original.pdf).

My system is Kubuntu 17.

Comment: What are bookmarks? Is that a feature of the reader, not of the PDF itself?

Comment: @Sparhawk As I understand, it is a feature of the PDF itself, which is accessible in different readers.

Comment: Can you give a clear example of how to create and retrieve a bookmark?

Comment: @Sparhawk In my case they were created in Adobe PDF (and are seen in any linux pdf-reader). Anyway, my question is how to preserve them, not how to make them.

Comment: Right, but if I don't even know what bookmarks are, then I can't help you. Also, if I can't even make bookmarks on my local system, then I can't test preserving them. So, there is no program called Adobe PDF. I assume you mean Adobe Reader? I launched Adobe Reader 9.5.5, but I can't find any option for bookmarks.

Comment: @Sparhawk Sorry, I meant Adobe Acrobat Pro, not available under linux. You can download a pdf with bookmarks e.g. from this link: http://www.novapdf.com/uploads/novapdf_en/media_items/pdf-example-bookmarks.original.pdf

Comment: @Sparhawk Thanks! The question is almost the same, but the proposed solution is not a solution, because for every particular case one will have to write a corresponding script to manage the info file with bookmarks. In that case it will be more convenient to have a virtual Windows with Acrobat. Anyway, very strange that there is no ready efficient solution under linux...